# Why doesn't My External Javascripts Run after an Ajax Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code in my index page which is pretty much the same for other pages except for the contents in #content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- TITLE -->
    <title>Home | The Ajax Project</title>
    <!-- Favicons -->

    <!-- STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <div class="nav-toggle">
                <a href="">
                    <span class="bar-1"></span>
                    <span class="bar-2"></span>
                    <span class="bar-3"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <section class="page-sect" data-bg="assets/images/slides/slide1.jpg">
        <div class="home-section">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                        <h1 class="main-heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto in vero a.   </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
        <section class="fullwidth">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h5>This is the first Page</h5>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nihil perspiciatis saepe harum eos quas aut. Quod blanditiis voluptatibus culpa beatae accusantium, consectetur nihil sequi ipsum, deserunt sapiente ratione repellat, amet enim? </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h5>This is the first Page</h5>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nihil perspiciatis saepe harum eos quas aut. Quod blanditiis voluptatibus culpa beatae accusantium, consectetur nihil sequi ipsum, deserunt sapiente ratione repellat, amet enim? </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



     <script id="runscript" type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
     <script id="runscript" type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ajax.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

And In my ajax.js, I have this code that calls other pages via ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-menu li a').each(function() {

        $(this).on('click', function() {
            var thisAttr = $(this).attr('href');

            function doAjax() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: thisAttr,
                    success: function(responseHtml) {

                        $('#content').html($(responseHtml).filter('#content').html());
                        var newTitle = $(responseHtml).filter('title').text();
                        document.title = newTitle;
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('error!!');
                    }
                });
            }

            $('#content').addClass('out');
            setTimeout(doAjax, 1000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#content').removeClass('out');
            }, 1000);

            return false;


        })

    })

});
```

Everything Works Fine. The Ajax Request goes as planned but the codes in these scripts      `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/test.js"></script>` don't work at all. My confusion is: why won't they work since they're still on the source page? I've tried everything including Eval(), no success!! Is there something I'm not doing right?

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context. Now you should tell what do you mean by not working? Expected behaviour compares to result you get. Error in console? What is `but the codes in these scripts`? Etc... If your issue is regarding any bound event on any element desendant of `#content`, then you surely need to delegate these events to `#content` level

Comment: @A. Wolff I've removed the IDs on the script tag thanks. By not working, I mean E.g I have a code in custom.js that alerts('Yay it works!!'). But after I run the Ajax, That script doesn't work again until I do a manual refresh of the page.. NO errors in console at all. The DOM acts like those scripts tags aren't even there.. hence all the codes in custom.js and test.js wont run after the Ajax call.

Comment: Provide more context regarding your code that doesn't work. Why should it be called again? Are these `script` part of the loaded `#content`?

Comment: ok. I have this code in custom.js :   var hasDataBgAttribute = $(".page-sect");
        hasDataBgAttribute.each(function(indx) {

            if ($(this).attr("data-bg")) {
                $(this).css("background", "url(" + $(this).data("bg") + ")");

            }

        });

Comment: I'm sorry but if you didn't provide a concrete sample to replicate your issue, i cannot help you more. You said you have `var hasDataBgAttribute =  ...` BUT why should it be recalled when you load new content?Is it part of a method (wrapped in a function)? If ya, then call this method on ajax success once you have replaced new content. Javascript/jQuery doesn't magically recall script because of DOM being updated by new content, that's not how it works

Comment: that gives this section :  <section class="page-sect" data-bg="assets/images/slides/slide1.jpg">
        <div class="home-section">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                        <h1 class="main-heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto in vero a.   </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section> it's background style via jquery. Works fine initial unitl I make an Ajax .

Comment: Okay here's another: I have simple code in test.js that just does alert('yay it worked'); on every page. Buh that doesn't work after I make my Ajax call. I don't want to have to call it via the success method or so.. I just want the scripts to run normally after every Ajax requests.

Comment: If you don't bind any event, it won't be call on each ajax request. Now you could use global ajax success method: `$(document).ajaxSuccess(handler);` where handler is the method to be called after each ajax request that success. To call same method when document is ready: `$(handler);`.

Comment: The Scripts aren't part of the loaded #content. They are part of the response text Ajax sends back and they even already exist on the page. The content in #content were filtered out from the respnse text and insert into the #content on the page. Now the script tags on the page won't have their codes run. My question is why won't they act

Comment: `My question is why won't they act` Well this is expected behaviour like i already said. If any js script should be recall, e.g like CSS rules are applied to any current and dynamic element, this would be a major performance issue. Just think about that it would mean on any change in DOM, all scripts, e.g jQuery library, should be reloaded too... **You have** to handle this part of logic yourself!

Comment: ok. How do I "handle this part of logic" , please? How DO I recall the scripts or make the DOM understand that they exist hence execute them?

Comment: I suggest you to read some basic tutos on how works javascript/jQuery because this is really, really, too broad question... NOW you could on ajax success (using global method as i already posted e.g) reload manually your scripts: `$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){$.getScript("assets/js/custom.js");//...});` BUT that's not how it should be done! If you want to make it correctly, set a method, e.g call it `initialize()` with all the logic you need inside it and recall it: `$(document).ajaxSuccess(initialize);`. For doc ready: `$(initialize);`.

Comment: I tried the $.getScript method, Worked perfectly. Buh the problem is it duplicates the scripts tags on every call. And eventually slows down the speed of the page. is there a way to stop the duplication?

Comment: Ya there is (search for how remove script, but that's useless anyway because removing script doesn't remove js from browser memory anyway...) And then that's a XY problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem   I told you how you should do it instead, set a method with all logic, recall this method **when** needed. Now there is a concept called data-binding. There is many libraries to handle this, e.g https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding   But that's not really what you need here, i guess...

Comment: I'm very new to jQuery A. Wolf. I'd like to try out your suggestion: data-binding, logic recall etc.. if only you provide me with a code sample. E.g a fiddle..? Pretty Pls..?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that `$(document).ready(XYZ);` will call XYZ exactly once - when the main page loads. It won't be called anymore when you change your page from within the ajax stuff. You therefore need to call the functions that are being called by `$(document).ready` again each time after the ajax stuff performed its changes.

Here's one (very quick-and-dirty) way to do it... (Note: Untested!)

First, add a line between the two script blocks like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">var updateCallbackCollector=[];</script>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ajax.js"></script>
```

Then, replace all instances of `$(document).ready(XYZ);` with `updateCallbackCollector.push(XYZ);` in your custom scripts with the exception of the `ajax.js` file.

Then, change the `ajax.js` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /////////// new stuff starts here ///////////
    for(var callback in updateCallbackCollector) {
        updateCallbackCollector[index]();
    }
    /////////// new stuff ends here ///////////

    $('.nav-menu li a').each(function() {

        $(this).on('click', function() {
            var thisAttr = $(this).attr('href');

            function doAjax() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: thisAttr,
                    success: function(responseHtml) {

                        $('#content').html($(responseHtml).filter('#content').html());
                        var newTitle = $(responseHtml).filter('title').text();
                        document.title = newTitle;

                        /////////// new stuff starts here ///////////
                        for(var index in updateCallbackCollector) {
                            updateCallbackCollector[index]();
                        }
                        /////////// new stuff ends here ///////////
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('error!!');
                    }
                });
            }

            $('#content').addClass('out');
            setTimeout(doAjax, 1000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#content').removeClass('out');
            }, 1000);

            return false;


        })

    })

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hauke. Tried it, didn't work! console error logs unexpected var in line ... But your explanation is enlightening. Thank you so much.

Comment: Whoops. I had a different programming language in mind when writing that piece of code. Please replace all instances of `foreach` with `for` as I've also already done by editing my answer.

Comment: Alright. Done! Error's gone, but still didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "the DOM treats them like they don't exist"? Do they not appear in the DOM tree? Or do they appear there but the code inside of them is simply not run?

Comment: They Appear there, But the code they link to doesn't run.. That's if the page is loaded via Ajax.

Comment: Looks like you have to give the code in these files. Otherwise giving help will be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer for this question during 3 last days. All the possible variants did not work with external script links. However I found a way to make it work. I want to share this solution, maybe it would be useful for anyone in future facing the same problem:

```
//Using scripts inserted through text editor
if ($('#page-main-content')) {
    $('#page-main-content').find("script").each(function (i) {

        var src = $(this).attr("src");      
        if (src != "undefined" && src != "") {

            //In case if we have external script
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = src;
            var charset = $(this).attr("charset");
            if (charset != "undefined" && charset != "") {
                script.charset = charset;
            }
            var divName = "div" + $.now();
            $(this).after('<div id="' + divName + '"></div>');

            //Remove initial script
            $(this).remove();

            var myDiv = document.getElementById(divName);
            myDiv.appendChild(script);

        } else {
            //In case if we have internal local script
            eval(document.getElementById("page-main-content").innerHTML);
        }
    });
}
```

Please note one important thing (I do not know why it is so): in case if you replace lines:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById(divName);
myDiv.appendChild(script);
```

with jQuery:

```
var myDiv = $('#' + divName);
myDiv.appendChild(script);
```

the script link will be inserted into div tag, however the script will not run... So, use native javascript function document.getElementById here as stated in my first code example above.

At mine everything worked fine. You can see a link of working web-site using this function: http://aikiclub.com.ua/.